# Xelement paring issue case insensitive

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xelement

How to parse `XElement` as case insensitive ?

Here is my code:

```
private void GetMyLayer(XElement myElement)
{
    Layer layer = new Layer();
    foreach (var myItem in myElement.Descendants("layeritem"))
    {
        if (myItem.Element("HyperLinkFields") != null)
           layer.ClickableHyperLinkFields = gisItem.Element("HyperLinkFields").Value.Split(',');
    }
}
```

This is working fine when `myItem` contains a field called `HyperLinkFields`, but when the field name is `HyperlinkFields` can't figure out how to do it as case insensitive manner.

Comment: Maybe a lambda expresion helps you. Something like: if(myItem.Element.Where(w=> w.Name.ToLower() == "hyperlinkfields).Any())

Comment: i have tried this , but cant , myItem.Element is a method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Xml` is case sensitive, one could have element with same name but different case, which is perfectly valid.

If you read the documentation, `Element` method returns *first* (in document order) child element with the specified `XName`, so you could play with custom code and achieve the same behavior.

```
var element = myItem.Elements()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name.LocalName.Equals(searchstring, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)); 

if(element != null)
{
    // Your logic 
    //layer.ClickableHyperLinkFields = element.Value.Split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try lambda expression:

```
var yourItems = myItem.Elements().Where( e => e.Name.LocalName.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() == "HyperLinkFields".ToLowerInvariant() );

if(yourItems.Count() > 0) {
   //do what you want here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse the VB.  This finds elements regardless of name casing.  Note that it finds all level3 elements.

```
    Dim someXML As XElement
    ' someXML = XElement.Load("path here") 'to load from file / uri
    ' for testing
    someXML = <root>
                  <level1 num="1">
                      <level2 num="1">
                          <LeveL3 num="1">l3 one</LeveL3>
                          <level3 num="2">l3 two</level3>
                      </level2>
                      <level2 num="2">
                          <lEVEl3 num="3">l3 one</lEVEl3>
                      </level2>
                  </level1>
                  <level1 num="1">
                      <level2 num="2">
                          <LEVel3 num="3">l3 one</LEVel3>
                      </level2>
                  </level1>
              </root>

    For Each xe As XElement In someXML...<level2>.Elements
        If xe.Name.LocalName.ToLower.Equals("level3") Then
            xe.Value = "found" ' just to show that ALL were found
        End If
    Next
```